# How to make an application "recognized" as an application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, matlab, i3-window-manager

I'm using ubuntu and i3 window manager.

To launch matlab I have to navigate to

> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019a/bin

and type ./matlab.

Other applications like firefox and atom are recognized as programs, and therefore I can type "firefox" or "atom" directly in the terminal, regardless of where I am, to launch them. Is it possible to make matlab recognized as an application to get the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append that directory to your `PATH`,

```sh
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2019a/bin"
```

This can be added to your `~/.bash_profile`, or `~/.bashrc` for persistence across reboots.